# url: stop capturing after space

Tags: regex, pcre

I try to parse content and find Soundcloud url. My regular expression works  but don't stop capturing after the space.

```
$re = '/((http:\/\/(soundcloud\.com\/.*|soundcloud\.com\/.*\/.*|soundcloud\.com\/.*\/sets\/.*|soundcloud\.com\/groups\/.*|snd\.sc\/.*))|(https:\/\/(soundcloud\.com\/.*|soundcloud\.com\/.*\/.*|soundcloud\.com\/.*\/sets\/.*|soundcloud\.com\/groups\/.*)))/i';
```

As you can see here https://regex101.com/r/4BZhlu/1 it doesn't stop when the url is inline.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Replace all `.*` with `\S*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex is way to complicated. First, as Wiktor stated, replace the `.*` with `\S*` (which means anything but a space character).

Then, you can regroups cases up to:

```
(https?:\/\/(soundcloud\.com\/\S*|snd\.sc\/\S*))
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/3jgPki/1)

Comment: Thanks @ThomasAyoub & @CasimireHippolyte
here is my final regex :

`$re = '/(https?:\/\/)?(soundcloud\.com\/\S*|snd\.sc\/\S*)/i';`

https://regex101.com/r/3jgPki/2